# asp.net core 6 EF scaffolding with Oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating Asp.net core 6 web api with oracle 19 as backend. i am using DB first approach and create model object from DB table. i used the below syntax,

```
 scaffold-dbcontext "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=TestDB.Test.com)(PORT=1717))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TestDB)));User Id=usename;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;Connection Lifetime=100000;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -o ModelFolder -f
```

Note : i removed the secured data and gave dummy data on the above code. I was able to generate the model from my backend. but having some issues with DB type. i am trying to call the EF query to get the data and facing cast issue. one of the table column is datatype is Number(3) and model got created as Byte?. when it try to bind the entity result, it gives me specified cast is not valid. its expecting Int. am not sure how to solve the issue. i should not be modified the auto generated model property to int. not sure is this ongoing issue with asp.net core with oracle. requesting any suggestion to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to call the EF query to get the data and facing cast
> issue. one of the table column is datatype is Number(3) and model got
> created as Byte?. when it try to bind the entity result, it gives me
> `"specified cast is not valid`"

It would be nicer, if you could add your database entity schema defination and the `asp.net core POCO Class`. Thus, based on the error, you should  consider following `data types` which usually treated as inconsistent within `Oracle` to `Asp.net core` entity scaffolding while generate automatically.

**Please Cheeck Following data type:**

`byte?` should be `long` in asp.net core,

`short?`  should be `int`

`bool?` should be changed to `int` if it contains number like `0` or `1` other than `oracle number` should be deal with `decimal`

**Note:** When we encounter `"specified cast is not valid`" it convery the meaning, `POCO Class` and `data entity model` error mostly related to defination of `asp.net core POCO` class which doesn't matached with the `database entity defination`. You could follow this official Chart for reference:

[image]

[image]

More details can be founded at [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings)

Comment: Thank you for the response Farid and here the details you asked for  `Thank you Farid for the reply and below is the extra details that you asked for `
public partial class SiteMapping   
{   
 public  FacilityId { get; set; } = null!;
        public string FacilityName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? SiteCode { get; set; }
        public byte? SiteId { get; set; }

}
ModelContext.cs
public virtual DbSet<SiteMapping> SiteMappings { get; set; } = null!;
 entity.Property(e => e.SiteId)
                    .HasPrecision(3)
                    .HasColumnName("SITE_ID");`

Comment: if could see the above code i posted, entity.Property(e => e.SiteId) .HasPrecision(3)  this is the one auto generated by the scaffolding. everything was systematic generation and i am not sure how to solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for you response, as explained earlier, check your oracle schema for `public byte? SiteId` property which data type scaffolding generated. It would be type of long.

Comment: Thanks for the response and once again sharing that oracle column data type is number(3) and scaffolding generated the column data type as  byte?.  also, on model context it created as <code>  entity.Property(e => e.SiteId) .HasPrecision(3) .HasColumnName("SITE_ID"); </code>

Comment: Make it long hope it will resolve your issue, oracle type of number 3 would have match either decimal or long, not byte. In addition, does your database schema contains like this `SITE_ID`?

Comment: yes, the column name in oracle is Site_Id. i should not change the type as long manually because every time when i refresh the model using scaffolding, it will override the changes and we have to keep this track  manually which is painful one.

Comment: In case of Oracle is the known issue please refer the document I have shared. Databasee like, SQL server, My SQL doesn't encounter this issuee. Hope I have pointed you the issue accordingly.

Comment: finally i found the why it uses byte for number(3) and information is stated below,

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/entityDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-4C48988B-CEA2-4193-95AC-949CCE90D601

For example, in Entity Framework 6, Oracle NUMBER(3,0) has a default mapping to .NET Byte. Oracle NUMBER(3,0) can store a value up to 999, while a .NET BYTE can store up to the value of 255

Comment: The point data-type from oracle to asp.net core, need to be fixed this was the main explanation of my answer, and I tried to describe that so far.

Comment: thanks for your time on this post. appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome, and glad to assist you.